# В WPF приложении в Windows 7 шрифт Palatino Linotype не отобажает верхний индекс

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

[image: На Windows 7]
 [image: На Windows 8]
Проблема с OpenType шрифтом Palatino Linotype в WPF приложении. На windows 8 приложение работает нормально, а вот в windows 7 верхний индекс отображается обычно. Я заметил, что проблема касается только цифр - буквы нормально отображаются в верхнем индексе. Я пробовал внедрить шрифт в приложение - ничего не меняется.

---

Дополнение.

С таким кодом:

```
<TextBlock Height="50" Width="80" FontFamily="Palatino Linotype" FontSize="22">
    14<Run Typography.Variants="Superscript">5k</Run>
</TextBlock>
```

получается правильно:

[image: правильный рендер]

А вот с таким (разница в содержимом индекса)

```
<TextBlock Height="50" Width="80" FontFamily="Palatino Linotype" FontSize="22">
    14<Run Typography.Variants="Superscript">5</Run>
</TextBlock>
```

неправильно:

[image: неправильный рендер]

Comment: Кстати заметил, если в верхнем индексе присутствует хоть одна буква, то все нормально. А если только цифры и символы, то в верхний индекс не попадает

Comment: А с другими шрифтами та же проблема наблюдается? И как вы кодируете верхний индекс?

Comment: [вот собственно проблема](https://cloud.mail.ru/public/MvE8/r4HUqhQ6E) . Да. С другими шрифтами так же.

Comment: Вы бы поместили код в вопрос в виде текста лучше.

Comment: Вариант 1: 
`<TextBlock Height="50"  Name="textBlock1" FontFamily="Palatino Linotype" FontSize="22" Width="80">
          14<Run Typography.Variants="Superscript">5k</Run> 
        </TextBlock>`
В этом случае 5k отображается в верхнем индексе.       
Вариант 2:
`<TextBlock Height="50"  Name="textBlock1" FontFamily="Palatino Linotype" FontSize="22" Width="80">
          14<Run Typography.Variants="Superscript">124</Run> 
        </TextBlock>` В этом случае 124 в верхний индекс не пойдет, потому что только цифры. Почему так получается? Так происходит на Windows XP и Windows 7, на win8 все ок

Comment: Странно. У меня на Win7 как раз с Palatino Linotype всё в порядке, а вот с Arial проблемы (причём как для `5`, так и для `5k`).

Comment: А какая у вас версия Visual Studio/.NET?

Comment: Является ли Arial opentype шрифтом я не знаю даже. Возможно у него и не должен отображаться индекс. Значит у вас palationo на windows 7 правильно работает в обоих случаях? Я проверял и на XP - та же история.  VS 2010 на xp вообще нет VS. Приложение создал, как framework 4.0

Comment: Да, Palatino на Win7 работает правильно в обоих случаях. У меня VS 2012 и .NET 4.5. Может быть, в этом разница. // Arial не OpenType, наверное, в этом проблема с ним.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Прошло не мало времени с момента публикации вопроса. Проблема с верхним индексом была  давно была решена мной. Возможно кому-нибудь будет полезно решение. Вместо Run.Typography.Variants="Superscript", следовало использовать Run.BaselineAlignment = BaselineAlignment.Superscript. В этом случае глюк пропадает. Следует помнить, что Run.BaselineAlignment = BaselineAlignment.Superscript не меняет размер шрифта, а как известно размер шрифта верхнего индекса должен быть меньше основного шрифта. Меняйте сами размер для верхнего индекса, иначе получится неразбериха.